# how to make user site security in umbraco 5

Tags: razor, umbraco, umbraco5

I am new in umbraco and I want to no how to make user site security in umbraco 5, using "LoginPartial.cshtml" and adding new fields to "RegisterPartial.cshtml".

thanks

Comment: If possible avoid v5: http://umbraco.com/follow-us/blog-archive/2012/6/13/v5-rip.aspx

Comment: I agree with raklos, v5 is discontinued

Comment: thanks raklos and Trikks for your help

Answer (score 1):

As you know Umbraco V5 is retire; you can try 4.x and do the above with user controls.